# 'SoftwareSerial' does not name a type in Adafruit Feather M0 Bluefruit LE

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, softwareserial

I am trying to create a software serial connection between Arduino Uno & Adafruit Feather M0 Bluefruit LE.

I am getting the following error in the M0 sketch:

```
Arduino: 1.8.1 (Windows 10), Board: "Adafruit Feather M0"

atcommand:60: error: 'SoftwareSerial' does not name a type

 SoftwareSerial bluefruitSS = SoftwareSerial(BLUEFRUIT_SWUART_TXD_PIN, BLUEFRUIT_SWUART_RXD_PIN);

 ^

atcommand:62: error: 'bluefruitSS' was not declared in this scope

 Adafruit_BluefruitLE_UART ble(bluefruitSS, BLUEFRUIT_UART_MODE_PIN,

                               ^

exit status 1
'SoftwareSerial' does not name a type
```

Here are the modifications I did to the atcommand sketch (in Adafruit BluefruitLE nRF51 library) before uploading to the M0:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#if not defined (_VARIANT_ARDUINO_DUE_X_) && not defined (_VARIANT_ARDUINO_ZERO_)
  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#endif

#include "Adafruit_BLE.h"
#include "Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI.h"
#include "Adafruit_BluefruitLE_UART.h"

#include "BluefruitConfig.h"


// Create the bluefruit object, either software serial...uncomment these lines

SoftwareSerial bluefruitSS = SoftwareSerial(BLUEFRUIT_SWUART_TXD_PIN, BLUEFRUIT_SWUART_RXD_PIN);

Adafruit_BluefruitLE_UART ble(bluefruitSS, BLUEFRUIT_UART_MODE_PIN,
                      BLUEFRUIT_UART_CTS_PIN, BLUEFRUIT_UART_RTS_PIN);


/* ...or hardware serial, which does not need the RTS/CTS pins. Uncomment this line */
// Adafruit_BluefruitLE_UART ble(BLUEFRUIT_HWSERIAL_NAME, BLUEFRUIT_UART_MODE_PIN);

/* ...hardware SPI, using SCK/MOSI/MISO hardware SPI pins and then user selected CS/IRQ/RST */
//Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI ble(BLUEFRUIT_SPI_CS, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_IRQ, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_RST);

/* ...software SPI, using SCK/MOSI/MISO user-defined SPI pins and then user selected CS/IRQ/RST */
//Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI ble(BLUEFRUIT_SPI_SCK, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_MISO,
//                             BLUEFRUIT_SPI_MOSI, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_CS,
//                             BLUEFRUIT_SPI_IRQ, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_RST);
```

I  tried to comment the if statement before `#include <SoftwareSerial.h>`, I got the following error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.1 (Windows 10), Board: "Adafruit Feather M0"

C:\Users\hadeel\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_modified_sketch_612073\atcommand.ino:18:30: fatal error: SoftwareSerial.h: No such file or directory

   #include "SoftwareSerial.h"

                              ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Adafruit Feather M0.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: SoftwareSerial is not available for the Zero core. There are so many HardwareSerial ports to use instead :) https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=341054.0

Comment: **THANK YOU** .. It finally works .. really appreciate your help ..